# How do you get code to run without interrupting other code in python?

Tags: python

I am making a clicker game called "Vehicles, Inc." where you run a car company. The main part is the user clicking a button to make a vehicle. Also, I have a function that sells vehicles. It sells a vehicle and then waits 1 second. The problem is, whenever I run it, the whole program stops for a second, which is not what I want. I was wondering if there was a way to run something without interrupting other code? I'm using python 3.9. Here's the code for sellVe (sellVehicle):

```
def sellVe():
    if totalVe >= 1: #if there is a vehicle to sell
        totalVe -= 1  #decrease the total vehicles by 1
        funds += 150  #increase funds by $150
        sleep(1)   #wait 1 second
```

Also, I would be running it in an infinite loop. So I basically just want a way to run this without interrupting the game's other code? Thanks!

Comment: Check https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: This is not a simple problem to solve. You should basically use multiple threads/processes, or `async` functions.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll check those out

Comment: @Diego Torres Milano I'm not really making much sense of that website... It doesn't really explain things that well. Is there another site you know of? Sorry!

Comment: you can start at https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/